# Kubernetes Ceph StorageClass with dynamic provisioning

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I'm trying to setup my Kubernetescluster with a Ceph Cluster using a storageClass, so that with each PVC a new PV is created automatically inside the ceph cluster.

But it doesn't work. I've tried a lot and read a lot of documentation and tutorials and can't figure out, what went wrong.

I've created 2 secrets, for the ceph admin user and an other user `kube`, which I created with this command to grant access to a ceph osd pool.

Creating the pool:
`sudo ceph osd pool create kube 128`

Creating the user:
`sudo ceph auth get-or-create client.kube mon 'allow r' \
osd 'allow class-read object_prefix rbd_children, allow rwx pool=kube' \
-o /etc/ceph/ceph.client.kube.keyring`

After that I exported both the keys and converted them to Base64 with:
`sudo ceph auth get-key client.admin | base64` and `sudo ceph auth get-key client.kube | base64`
I used those values inside my secret.yaml to create kubernetes secrets.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: "kubernetes.io/rbd"
metadata:
  name: ceph-secret
data:
   key: QVFCb3NxMVpiMVBITkJBQU5ucEEwOEZvM1JlWHBCNytvRmxIZmc9PQo=
```

And another one named ceph-user-secret.

Then I created a storage class to use the ceph cluster

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/rbd

parameters:
  monitors: publicIpofCephMon1:6789,publicIpofCephMon2:6789
  adminId: admin
  adminSecretName: ceph-secret
  pool: kube

  userId: kube
  userSecretName: ceph-kube-secret

  fsType: ext4
  imageFormat: "2"
  imageFeatures: "layering"
```

To test my setup I created a PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-eng
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

But it gets stuck in the pending state:

```
#kubectl get pvc
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc-eng   Pending                                      standard       25m
```

Also, no images are created inside the ceph kube pool.
Do you have any recommendations how to debug this problem?

I tried to install the ceph-common ubuntu package on all kubernetes nodes. I switched the kube-controller-manager docker image with an image provided by AT&T which includes the ceph-common package.

https://github.com/att-comdev/dockerfiles/tree/master/kube-controller-manager

Network is fine, I can access my ceph cluster from inside a pod and from every kubernetes host.

I would be glad if anyone has any ideas!

Comment: Please check my blog post for each step https://crondev.com/kubernetes-persistent-storage-ceph/

Comment: @AlenKomljen the link is unreachable now

Comment: @vikas027 Here is the new one https://akomljen.com/using-existing-ceph-cluster-for-kubernetes-persistent-storage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `annotation: ReadWriteOnce`.
As you can see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/ (Persistent Volumes section) RBD devices does not support ReadWriteMany mode. Choose different volume plugin (CephFS, for example) if you need read and write data from PV by several pods.

Answer (score 0):

As an expansion on the accepted answer.....

RBD is a remote block device. ie an external hard drive like iSCSI. The filesystem is interpreted by the client container so can only be written by a single user or corruption will happen.

CephFS is a network aware filesystem similar to NFS or SMB/CIFS. That allows multiple writes to different files. The filesystem is interpreted by the Ceph server so can accept writes from multiple clients.